# Geth Contract Deployment Error : Contract transaction couldn't be found after 50 blocks

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-development, private-blockchain

I have created a private blockchain and tried to deploy a simple contract on blockchain. But the deployment throws the following error -

```
Error sending/minig the transaction: {
    "message": "Contract transaction couldn't be found after 50 blocks",
    "name": "Error"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure that your is synced.

There is an open issue in a Truffle repo which may help https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/677